# Не появляется SnackBar в фрагменте

Tags: android, snackbar

Пытаюсь показать snackBar в фрагменте. Вот разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/received"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_ms"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:theme="@style/Widget.BottomNavigationView"
        app:itemBackground="@color/bottom_color_2"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selected_text_2"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selected_text_2"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
        app:menu="@menu/message_center_menu" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/view_2"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:background="@color/test_color" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/no_messages"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:visibility="gone" />


    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list_res"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Сначала делал так:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(relativeLayout, "Item was removed from the list.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                snackbar.setAction("UNDO", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        adapter.restoreItem(item, viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                    }
                });

                snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                snackbar.show();
```

бар не появлялся, дальше решил что возможно неправильно назначен корневой элемент где я пытаюсь показать, поэтому подключил главный relativeLayout, но я все-равно не вижу ничего. Поигрался с марджинами, но все-равно ничего не вижу. В интернете в основном пишут что проблема в том что неправильно выбран корневой элемент, но я уже по всякому пытался, и ничего не помогло. Может кто знает в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: а как объявлен `relativeLayout` ?

Comment: @iFr0z, в onCreate() через глобальную переменную

Comment: Вместо `relativeLayout` попробуйте указать `((Activity)context).findViewById(relativeLayout)`

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, не помогло, все-равно ничего не появилось

Comment: попробуйте лучше `getActivity().`, чтобы так контекст не тянуть

Comment: @iFr0z, все-равно ничего не выводит :( уже по разному пробовал, и ничего не видно

Comment: тогда лучше все таки корневой лэйаут поменять или обшить ещё и `coordinator`'ом

Comment: поменял на `coordinator`, но все-равно ничего, пробовал в родительской активности вывести бар, но там тоже не показывает, может я где-то в другом месте ошибаюсь?

Comment: @iFr0z, я думаю может проблема в том что у меня наверху и внизу висит bottomNavigationView? я вот попробовал применить другие марджины и что-то появилось но не там где нужно, то есть появилось вверху экрана вместо низа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение проблемы оказалось на поверхности. Так получается что вероятнее всего мой snackBar перекрывался bottomNavigationView. Пришлось поднимать snackBar и поменять мой корневой лейаут с relative на coordinator, а бар я показал так:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootView.findViewById(R.id.received_Layout), "Item was removed from the list.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                snackbar.setAction("UNDO", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        adapter.restoreItem(item, position);
                        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
                    }
                });

                CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) snackbar.getView().getLayoutParams();
                params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, bottomNavigationView.getHeight());
                snackbar.getView().setLayoutParams(params);
                snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                snackbar.show();
```

может кому поможет.